# Cannot connect to docker container/image containing Ruby API

Tags: ruby, docker

## Edit:

It appears that my problem is not a problem with Docker, my host, or my running application, from within my container I am able to curl localhost:9292 and get an API response from my app, whats happening is that my `EXPOSE` statement in my Dockerfile is not exposing the port in my base image (Debian)

---

This is my first time building my own container, I have a Grape API that I have turned into a docker image, unfortunately, when I run it I can't seem to connect to it via IP address / Port

```
#Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.4.1

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN gem install rubygems-update --no-ri --no-rdoc

ENV WD /app

RUN mkdir $WD

ADD . $WD

WORKDIR $WD

RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 9292

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup"] # defaults to 9292
```

This successfully builds into a nearly usable image

```
aronlilland:receiving_log_api (master)$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             
SIZE
receiving_log_api   latest              25061200fe6e        11 seconds ago      1.08GB
ruby                2.4.1               e7ca4a0b5b6d        6 months ago        684MB
```

I am starting my application by running it how I would from the command line

```
aronlilland:receiving_log_api (master)$ docker run -p 9292:9292 receiving_log_api bundle exec rackup -p 9292
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I have tried binding the IP address to 0.0.0.0 by doing
`docker run -p 9292:9292 receiving_log_api bundle exec rackup -p 9292 --host 0.0.0.0`

`docker ps` says that the application is running on the specified port, except whenever i try to connect to it from my browser or API utility it responds that nothing is running on that IP address and port, I have tried `localhost:9292` `127.22.10.11:9292` `0.0.0.0:9292`

```
aronlilland:receiving_log_api (master)$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
85c7f58994ec        receiving_log_api   "/bin/sh -c 'bundle …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9292->9292/tcp   receiving-log
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong, I know I have to be close :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you don't expose the port in Dockerfile. Add

`EXPOSE 8383` in Dockerfile before CMD

For Example:

```
    #rest of the dockerfile
    RUN bundle install
    EXPOSE 8383
    CMD bundle exec rackup # defaults to 9292
```

And when you run the container do `docker run -p9292:9292 <container name/id>`. you may change the default port and expose it instead of 9292 and also could run on daemon mode passing `-d`.

For more info https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: Tried that, and tried it again just now, unfortunately not working out even with daemon mode @Laksitha Ranasingha

Comment: fixed the $WD, i didnt have that locally, I had it correct locally :) but unfortunately no @Laksitha Ranasignha

Comment: Maybe, try with <host_ip>:9292 or exec into the container and do a curl on localhost.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by <host_ip>:9292 when using rackup you have to use --host <ip_address> to bind the Puma server to the IP address desired @Laksitha Ranasignha

Comment: I can see you have already tried host IP. So that's fine. Have you rebuilt the image and run a new container using that image after adding EXPOSE?

Comment: Ranasignha I havent tried doing anything with docker-compose.yml yet if thats what you mean, before I get that far the application should be reachable from my local dev computer, but i have rebuilt the image about 200 times :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167488/discussion-between-laksitha-ranasingha-and-ochero).